# Webpack: compile less files without using imports

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I'm trying to migrate to webpack from grunt and trying to figure out the best way to bundle less files during development .

Is there a way to configure webpack to build less files into a bundle without having to use imports ?

The issue here is that the project is based on es5 Javascript.

Comment: You can create styles.less file, import all .less files into it and add it as a new entry point like `config.entry = { styles: './app/app.js' }` (dont forget to add less-loader)